# Derivative of $y$ if $y=2x^5 + \arctan(5y)$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to have $y'$ in terms of $x$, but i can t get that. I get some recursive relation.

Comment: Yeah, most results from implicit differentiation will involve both x and y, I don't think you can simplify any further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Note that we get: $$y’ = 10x^4 + \frac{1}{1+25y^2} \frac{d}{dx}(5y) $$ $$\implies y’ = 10x^4 + \frac{1}{1+25y^2}[5y’] \implies y’ = \, ?$$

Note: It may be difficult to eliminate $y$, however.

Answer (score 0):

$$ y' = 10x^4 + {1\over 1+25y^2}5y'$$ so $$ y' = {2x^4(1+25y^2)\over 5y^2}$$